# An undirected graph having n edges, then find out no. of vertices that graph have?

Tags: data-structures, undirected-graph

An undirected graph having 'n' number of edges, then find out number of vertices that graph have?‏‏‎

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a CS or math question, not programming.

Answer (score 1):

Since an edge is a connection between to vertices, the amount of vertices is at max 2n.

The amount of vertices is at minimum n+1. (This is pretty logical if you imagine that you have 2 edges - then you will at minimum have 3 vertices, because each edge must connect 2 vertices)

So if e = n, then n+1 <= v <= 2n

Comment: This is not correct. Both the upper bound v <= 2n and the lower bound n+1 <= v are false. The upper bound is false because you can have arbitrarily many vertices if you allow isolated vertices (vertices that don't have an incident edge). The lower bound is false unless the graph is acyclic; for instance, take the triangle graph. It has 3 edges and 3 vertices.

Comment: Then there is no correct answer to the question because specifications are not clear :D

Comment: You can add explicit assumptions to your answer, to avoid making false statements about general graphs. For instance, if the graph is a forest, then n+1 <= v. If the graph is a tree, then n+1 = v. If the graph has no isolated nodes, then v <= 2n. If the graph is a cycle, then v = n. If the graph is complete, then n = v(v-1)/2 so v = (1 + sqrt(1+8n))/2. In all graphs, n <= v(v-1)/2 so v >= (1 + sqrt(1+8n))/2.

Answer (score 0):

There is no exact formula for the number of vertices in terms of number of edges in the general case.  However, if you take special cases, you can say more:  if the graph is a tree, then the number of vertices is one more than the number of edges.